# Built-in tools for fast extraction of tuples of a given grade with respect to grading on [1, 2, ..., n]

Tags: python, performance, combinations, python-itertools

I am in the process of coding 2 mathematical combinatorial operations that I want to iterate (as) many times (as possible), so speed is obviously crucial.

Here is an example of what I want to do as fast and efficiently as possible for any positive integer n and any grading (see example below).

**Remark:** This is a self-motivated question coming from mathematical experimentations with Sage.
Many thanks in advance for your help.

**Example:**
Let us take n = 6, and the set S = {1, 2, ..., n} = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}.
There are binomial(6, 2) = 15 couples

```
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 6)]
```

in increasing order that we can extract from S.
The built-in tool I was advised to use in order to obtain the above list is the following:

```py
from itertools import combinations
n = 6
iterable = list(range(1, n+1))
r = 2
print(list(combinations(iterable, r)))
```

**Question 0:** Is there anything faster in Python?

Now let me choose a grading on the set S in the form of a function from S to {1, 2, 3}

grading: 1, 2, 3 --> 1 and 4, 5 --> 2 and 6 --> 3

I have decided to store this function as a dictionary as follows:

```py
grading = {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 3}
```

With respect to this grading, we can compute the grade of elements, couples, or tuples constructed from S.

Examples:

- grade(2) = 1
- grade(5) = 2
- grade((2, 5)) = grade(2) + grade(5) = 1 + 2 = 3
- grade((2, 3, 5)) = 1 + 1 + 2 = 5

1 -  First Construction:

I want all the couples with grade equal to g0 = 4.
Here is an obvious way to do it, which is built naively on the previous lines of code:

```py
g0 = 4
gradedList = []
for couple in list(combinations(iterable, 2)):
    grade = grading[couple[0]] + grading[couple[1]]
    if grade == g0:
        gradedList.append(couple)
print(gradedList)
```

This yields

```
[(1, 6), (2, 6), (3, 6), (4, 5)]
```

as desired.

**Question 1:** Is there a built-in way to obtain gradedList and/or what is the fastest way to do this with Python?

2 - Second Construction:

Now I want to extract all the increasing 3-tuples (i, j, k) with grade equal to 4, and which starts with i = 1.

In other terms, I want the following list:

```
[(1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5), (1, 3, 4), (1, 3, 5)]
```

Of course, this can be obtained as follows:

```py
newIterable = list(range(2, n+1))
secondGradedList = []
for couple in list(combinations(newIterable, 2)):
    grade = grading[1] + grading[couple[0]] + grading[couple[1]]
    if grade == g0:
        secondGradedList.append((1,) + couple)
print(secondGradedList)
```

**Question 2:** Is there a built-in way to obtain secondGradedList and/or what is the fastest way to do this with Python?

Thanks,
Julien

Comment: You don't need to convert `iterable` to `list` before passing it to `combinations`. You can just pass `range(1, n+1)` itself. It'll somewhat reduce the execution time. You can refer [Python doc about `itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

Comment: And for the "First Construction" and "Second Construction", I think we can save much time if we get the possible grade partitions (like [partitions in number theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory))) first, and construct the combinations from the partitions. If we use this method, we'll need `grading_reverse = {1: [1, 2, 3], 2: [4, 5], 3: [6]}` instead of `grading = {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 3}`.

Comment: Just to add to @Gorisanson's comment: the second call to `list` in your for loop is not needed either. Instead of generating those lists, `range` and `combinations` are iterators that generate new list elements as you go, without ever having to store more than the current element of the (possibly infinite) sequence.

Comment: @Gorisanson Thanks. How do you suggest we construct the combinations from the partition? I see how to loop using grading_reverse, and I see that this will be much better if I restrict (i, j) to i in grade k and j in grade 4-k. No more if tests. Do you think there is a faster built-in method?

Comment: @ojdo Thanks, will do.

Comment: @Julien I don't know surely, but I think you need to build a custom function for it.